# Is there a way to continue a partially finished MinGW build?

Tags: compiler-construction, build

I am just trying to become familiar with MinGW (and with more complex command-line compiler tools)

I have a really giant project to build, I successfully managed to generate the makefile with CMake, and started mingw.

After more than an hour of hard work, and building dozens of libraries successfully, the build ended in an error. It seems I added an option in CMake which is not supported in my system. My problem is, I cannot figure out a way to just skip that library and continue with the build process. If I remove the option in CMake and start mingw again, it starts from the beginning and rebuilds everything, even those libraries which are already built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the -k install flag, ie:

```
make -k install
```

when generating the make file.

=====================

Based on our discussion below:

- What you're asking for is not possible afaik. Make style build systems are designed to fail on error - the "no partial installs policy". If a build doesn't complete 100%, the system aborts.
- Makefile creators are expected to inspect each dependency and decide, for each one individually, whether it's a definite or optional requirement.

Comment: I generate the make file with CMake. It's just too big and complex to be hand-written. You mean instead of letting CMake generate it, I should run make from the command line myself?

Comment: I mean I have two actions to perform in CMake: configure and Generate. First I configure, and after that, instead of performing "generate" from the CMake GUI, I should run make myself? I see no options to add command line arguments to `make` in the CMage GUI

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Are you using a Windows GUI version of CMake to generate the make file, then an included version of make in MinGW to run the actual build?

Comment: That said, the build process tends to be an all or nothing process - there's no way to do a "partial install". What you probably want to do is to make the library that's missing optional, or remove it altogether from the list of requirements for your build.

Comment: Yes, I use a Windows GUI version of CMAke to generate the make file, and then I run MinGW from the command line to run the build.

Comment: My problem is, that there are really, really lot of libraries. At the beginning I have no idea which will be supported in my system. What I do is generating the makefile, starting a build, it stops after hours at say 39%, then I remove the library, then start again, after another few hours it stops at say 48% and so on. I would like to skip that "remove the library which did not work and start again" phase. The good news for me is, that in both occasions the library was an unimportant one. However, Is still would like to build as many libraries as possible.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then. Make type systems are purposefully built to avoid the kind of behaviour you're looking for. They almost always (and in your case specifically) expect the developer that is putting out a tool to explicitly, and carefully, go over each and every included library and decide if it's crucial, or optional (and manually modify the build as appropriate).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This means the only way for me is to mark everything except the absolutely necessary core libraries as optional.